# Error: configure: error: ln doesn't support --relative when building Systemd

Tags: linux, centos, systemd, autoconf

While installing systemd version 221 on CentOS 6.9 using following steps:

```
# wget https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/systemd-221.tar.xz
# tar -xJf systemd-221.tar.xz
# cd systemd-221
# ./configure
```

`configure` is failing with the following output:

```
checking for sulogin... /sbin/sulogin
checking for mount... /bin/mount
checking for umount... /bin/umount
configure: error: *** ln doesn't support --relative ***
```

Although I have installed all the required yum-devel as well.

```
# yum install gcc intltool gperf glib2-devel
# yum search xz-devel
```

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on [the Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) (or alternatively on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour)).

Comment: Well seems like Not just Linux-Unix Issue to me, SystemD is also a Separate topic as well.

Comment: Yes Just Found, SystemD does not run on CentOS6, One need to Upgrade to Centos7 to Run SystemD smoothly. Took 1 hour to find that, IMHO This should be easily available on internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> checking for sulogin... /sbin/sulogin
> checking for mount... /bin/mount
> checking for umount... /bin/umount
> configure: error: ln doesn't support --relative
> ```

CentOS 6 is too old. The version of Coreutils it supplies is too old.

It looks like [Coreutils](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils) has a fix for `ln --relative` dated 2014-03-13 via [commit e52293aa7fcf](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/commit/e52293aa7fcf). Also see [`ln.c`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/ln.c) history:

> ln: --relative: fix updating of existing symlinks
>
> Don't dereference an existing symlink being replaced. I.E. generate
>   the symlink relative to the symlink's containing dir, rather than to
>   some arbitrary place it points to.
>
> - src/ln.c (convert_abs_rel): Don't consider the final component of the symlink name when canonicalizing, as we want to avoid
>     dereferencing the final component.
> - tests/ln/relative.sh: Add a test case.

Red Hat is infamous for supplying antique software. This is why you avoid Red Hat software if you can. Fedora is OK because it is always up to date. But Red Hat and CentOS are the pits...

Comment: Yes CentOS6 is too old for SystemD, Thanks for Detailed Explanation!

Comment: @arshpreet - You can update Coreutils if you like. But I would advise against it because a Coreutils bug fix could break your existing installation. Coreutils is one of those packages you mostly leave alone. You may be able to update _just_ `ln` command. Build a new Coreutils, and install it into `/opt` with `--prefix=/opt`. Then, backup `ln` and copy `/opt/bin/ln` in its place.